# How does this proposition imply that every compact region in the plane bounded by a regular polygon is a closed $2$-cell?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, proof-explanation

From *Intro to Topological Manifolds* by Lee:

[image]

---

After the proof, the author writes: **"every compact region in the plane bounded by a regular polygon is a closed $2$-cell"**.

However, these regions:

[image]

although not convex, are compact and bounded by some polygon.

**So, how does this proposition imply that every compact region in the plane bounded by a regular polygon is a closed $2$-cell?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, when Lee says "bounded by a regular polygon", he does not mean "contained within a regular polygon"; after all, a finite collection of points in the plane is also bounded in this sense, and it's certainly not a 2-cell.

Instead, I would take "region bounded by a regular polygon" to mean "the entire region enclosed by a regular polygon", which is convex. Lee seems to be using "polygon" to mean just the boundary, rather than this whole region.

Comment: That's right. The definition of "polygon" that I had in mind is the image of a simple closed curve consisting of finitely many (straight) line segments. The "region bounded by a polygon" is the union of the polygon together with the bounded component of its complement. Note that the two regions drawn by @AlJebr are not bounded by polygons.